Cohomology ring of $BPin(n)$ with Z coefficients
I cannot find any reference for the characteristic classes of $Pin(n)$  with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$.

What is the cohomology ring $H^*(BPin(n); \mathbb Z)$ ? Is it true that $H^*(BPin(2); \mathbb Z)\simeq \mathbb Z[x,y]/ y^3 ?$

Can anybody provide me with a reference computing these characteristic classes? I would be happy even with the case of $Pin(2)$.
